# How to stream raw synthesized PCM audio in C++/CX Windows 8 apps?

Tags: c++, audio, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Simply put, I want my C++/CX XAML Windows 8 app to output continuous synthesized sound (*not* sound effects). However I've been looking all over the Web and I cannot figure out how to get the system feed it buffers of PCM samples (or better, have it ask me for them through callbacks) for them to be played. I would use the old `waveOut*` APIs, however they are banned in Store app development.

So, what is the simplest way to do this? Please note that I am *not* interested in playing media files (.wav, .mp3) or web audio streaming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do this with www.portaudio.com?

Comment: PortAudio sadly doesn't appear to support Windows Store apps (however I could be wrong).

Comment: That is a major bummer. Could you bring this up on the PA mailing list? I don't do windows, but I'm sure they would want to rectify the situation if they can.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use WASAPI which is enabled in Windows Store apps. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will get you started with how to use the API to render audio. One annoyance is that WASAPI devices generally don't resample for you so you'll have to be willing to go with what the device is using (probably 44.1kHz or 48kHz) or do the resampling yourself (for which you can make use of the [Resampler Media Foundation transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff819070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).